Open all external links in Chrome browser instead of the in-app browser
my website mainly receives traffic through in-app browsers. However, some tools on my website don't function properly within the in-app browser. Therefore, I've implemented links to access these tools. When users visit my website using an in-app browser, instead of loading the tool directly, they see a link saying "Click here to start the tool." I want this link to open the tool page in the Chrome browser. I've attempted to achieve this with the following code, but it doesn't work in all in-app browsers, such as Skype. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, I have other links to external websites that are also tool websites, and I want these links to open in Chrome as well.
<button id="cta-button" class="button">Open Link in Chrome</button>

<script>
// Function to check if the browser supports the intent:// scheme
function supportsIntentScheme() {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'intent://foo#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end';
  return a.protocol === 'intent:';
}

// Function to open the link in Chrome browser
function openInChrome(url) {
  const intentUrl = 'intent://' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end';
  window.location.href = intentUrl;
}

// Flag to indicate whether to fallback to direct link opening
let fallbackToDirectLink = false;

// Event listener to check if the browser supports the intent:// scheme before loading the link
window.addEventListener('beforeload', function(event) {
  if (!supportsIntentScheme()) {
    fallbackToDirectLink = true;
  }
}, true);

// Event listener for page load to handle fallback
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Event listener for the CTA button
  document.getElementById('cta-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // URL to open in Chrome
    const urlToOpen = 'example.com';

    // Open the URL in Chrome if supported, otherwise open directly
    if (!fallbackToDirectLink) {
      openInChrome(urlToOpen);
    } else {
      window.location.href = urlToOpen;
    }
  });
});
</script>
 

